# Prevent opening a page except for through proper login

Tags: javascript

I am building a site where I would give access to a couple of pages only through a login script. I have used the following code and can successfully prevent opening of the page directly typing the URL in address bar from chrome.

```
if (document.referrer == "") {
    window.stop();
    alert('Unauthorised attempt to open admin page ..... !!');
    location.href='index.html';
}
```

I have put the code in the end of the head section of the html page. Problem is this bit of code is appearing to be invisible to IE and hence the page is opening by simply typing the URL in address bar. I have come to know that it is a bug sort of thing about IE that document.referrer is of no use in it. What is the way out? Can anybody give a solution please.

Sukalyan

Comment: This code offers absolutely no security whatsoever.  You're delivering the page to the user, and then suggesting that the user doesn't look at it if they're not supposed to.  Security is a *server-side* concern.

Comment: the approach of using script login is not good in my opinion disabling script and typing the url have you thought about that ?

Comment: Don't do this. By the time you've prevented users from accessing the page, the page is already on their computer.

Comment: @Sukalyan see how many are already agreeing to this ,we all suggest you take a different router preferably serverside authentication

Comment: You should probably google "ASP.NET Forms Authentication".  The topic is probably too long for an SO answer, but this should get you started.

Comment: please, security must be placed on server side

Comment: What if this code is run befor loading the document?

Comment: What if I disable the javascript of my browser?

Comment: @SukalyanGhoshal: 1) That's impossible.  You can't execute code *before* the code exists.  2) Doesn't matter, it's still executing *client-side*.  You're *asking* the user to maintain your security for you.  They may choose not to.

Comment: I understand what you say and it is the best way to leave it for the server to take care of the security issue. But still, academically speaking, is there any way just to accomplish what I suggested?

Comment: @SukalyanGhoshal: `"accomplish what I suggested"` - And what is that exactly?  If this code isn't "working" (whatever that means) in IE, how specifically is it failing?  Is there an error?  Is it executing at all?  When you debug it, where/how does it fail?  We've already pointed out that this code *fundamentally* doesn't do what you're trying to do.  So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: The following code put at the end of the head section can detect it the browser is IE  if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )) 
            {
             
              
            } Then I can put some code inside the if block that will stop loading the body or rest of the page.

Comment: The stop() method is not supported by Internet Explorer.  Put a try catch block around it or just take it out.

Answer (score 0):

Some searching revealed this :
using if(!document.referrer) instead of if (document.rferrer == '') makes it and the best thing is that it works with both IE and chrome !!

so - good bye and thanks to everybody

Regards

Sukalyan